# How can i open React App on local network?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created an app using the Create React App.
When I start the server using Npm start it shows

You can now view the player in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.104:3000

When i access this on my network which is on my android device(chrome for android) it shows `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACABLE`.

I cannot access the app from my network, from any device.
I am using Windows 10 for the development.
I have also tried turning firewall and antivirus off.

Comment: Seems like a networking problem of some kind - this should work if both devices are on the same local network. You could also try creating a free account and using ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to access your app through the public internet.

Comment: works fine with ngrok. Also both of my devices are on same wifi network. I tried to switch to my mobile hotspot and it started working but it doesn't works when connected to the Wifi.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Have you tried to disable firewall?

Comment: Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68551547/running-localhost-react-app-on-mobile-phones/74729561#74729561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open CMD and type ipconfig
2. Note your public IP
3. Openmobile web browser and open IP address with Port number.
   i.e: 192.159.0.132:3000/app_route

OR try `ngrok`

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue after switching to a new laptop (Windows 11).  My issue was that my home network was flagged as a public network, and when I switched it to a private network my laptop was now discoverable and my react apps and other services were again available on my other LAN devices.