# Running localhost react app on mobile phones

Tags: reactjs

I need to connect my react app to my local network by typing in localhost on any device. Im not sure if this is possible. Right now I use my computers IP address and I type the address into my phone browser with port 300 and it works. The only thing is that I am using auth0 and I need a list of callback urls for it to work. Basically anything other than localhost in the url will be blocked. So i need to type in localhost:3000 on my phone and my react app needs to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like lvh.me that resolves back to the IP you provide as the subdomains. This will be fairly stable, but you will need to specify the domain to Auth0.

For example, if your IP address is 10.0.0.5 and your app is running on port 3000, from your local network you would visit http://10.0.0.5.lvh.me:3000/ from your phone. This request would resolve to `10.0.0.5:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it's not possible. The localhost refers to `127.0.0.1` IP in your computer which is like a globally followed convention for all the devices in the world.

Your router assigns an IP like `167.12.124.12` for each of the devices connected to it and if any other device is connected to the same router, they can communicate with each other by using the IP the router created for the devices.

The router assigned IP won't change unless your device goes offline for some reason. Try adding the IP as an allowed URL in the list of URLs in Auth0.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure both your phone and computer are connected the same wifii. Then, try to figure out how to find your IPv4 Address. The screenshot below shows where to find it on mac, I guess you can find it by typing ipconfig on terminal, too. This IPv4 address is your localhost. I usually run my react app's on port 3000 so when you go to **yourIPv4address:3000** on your mobile phone's browser you can see your react app on mobile. Hope it helps. Good luck.